# Can we have a "OP does not respond to queries" close reason?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Example question:

[Unexpected Timer Conflicts (Uno)](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/10285/unexpected-timer-conflicts-uno)

Marked as unanswered. However a reply (later converted to a comment) asking for more information has been completely ignored.

How can this ever be answered if the OP does not post code? And for other posts if the OP does not state what Arduino they have?

---

Suggest a "vote to close" reason: Clarification to question sought: none provided.

I'm guessing that a question that is months old, and getting no activity has been abandoned as "too hard" or answered elsewhere.

Meanwhile we get another "unanswered question" on our list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If there isn't enough information to answer the question then I think "Unclear what you're asking" is a suitable close reason.

Comment: Indeed - though a more effective mechanism for disposing of questions which have been abandoned in this state for months could be useful.  As an aside, questions questionably migrated from other sites where they are also on topic sometimes get stuck in this state if the asker does not follow the involuntary relocation of their question here.